# Will I need to build up my readiness level again to get the good ending on the extended cut?

Tags: mass-effect-3

So, I beat ME3 a while ago, and  I'm curious about the extended cut. When I last completed it, I had 96% readiness level and well over the limit for the best ending. Now, it has been so long that I have 50% readiness level, and not really enough assets to get the best ending.

If I resume from the save file [recommended by EA](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/74782/15643), will I need to be at the same (or a similar) readiness level again to see the best ending, or will I still be able to get that same ending even with only 50% readiness level even though my war assets don't add up to enough now?

Comment: Pretty sure the math is going to be the exact same, so if you wouldn't get the best ending at your current readiness (sans extended cut) you won't get it with the extended cut

Comment: @BenBrocka Yeah, I'm more just curious if it somehow 'saved' the value and I don't have to get the readiness again or if it calculates it every time. Mostly because the achievement is unlocked at a specific time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In releasing the Extended Cut, EA/Bioware also reduced the EMS requirement for the various "endings". Specifically, the cutoff is now 3100 EMS, down from 4000 (With 50% readiness, this is a sizable 1800 reduction).

Readiness, in this case, is irrelevant. The only thing that effects the ending is EMS, which Readiness is but one part of.

Since you have to resume from before the assault on the cerberus base *anyway* (the same place the game kicks you out post credits if you choose to continue), you can still fly around and pick up as many War Assets as you have left to claim.

You'll have to judge for yourself if you can hit 3100 EMS or not. (If you assault the Cerberus Base with at least 3050 EMS, you'll clear this threshold)

Alternatively, have you considered simply watching the endings online, on a video service such as youtube? It still saves you from having to replay the rest of the game, and figuring out if you can get the best ending.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to justify playing it through. Obviously EA wants me to have kept playing multiplayer, and that wasn't going to happen. Youtube it is. Thanks for the info