# What before-the-ending changes are there in the Extended Cut DLC?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I quickly ran through the Extended Cut DLC last night and it's pretty clear that the post-decision outro sequence has been modified and extended.

However, during the run up to this point (I loaded from a save just before flying the Normandy to Earth to start the assault) I noticed one fairly obvious addition:

> The Evac of your two selected squad mates, thus ensuring they are on the Normandy as required by the original endings.

I'm wondering if I missed any others, so, **what are all the changes made to the game that happen *before* the start of the outro sequence?**

Comment: Good question, the Extended cut DLC was advertised as *new cinematics and epilogue scenes that will expand upon Mass Effect 3's original ending by providing more closure to Commander Shepard's story* - Meaning these are undocumented, so it would be interesting to know if we can come up with a list of *other* changes as a result of this DLC.

Comment: Well I can only tell from my playthrough yesterday (so I just leave it as a comment) - but before the actualy outro (meaning after chosing one of the 4 endings) I noticed the following changes:
- Run to the Conduit: Normandy picks up injured crew members
- When you get up to the citadel: You see a bit more fighting in space and Hackett getting a note that you made it to the citadel
- At the catalyst: New dialogue options

So thats all I noticed

Comment: @Toby, why not post that as an answer instead of a comment..? It might not be a complete list (I don't know, otherwise I wouldn't have asked), but it will at least be a good start.

Comment: I just prefer giving solid, complete answers instead of just some wild thoughts of me ^^

Comment: Similar question, but only for the ending change http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/74766/1134 (this question was specific to pre-ending changes). Maybe we should merge these into one "What changed in the Extended Content DLC?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer - I don't think there are any changes before the final rush towards the beam.

Long answer - [This page](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3:_Extended_Cut) on the Mass Effect 3 wikia site details a lot of changes *after* the approach to the beam scene that constitutes the start of the outro sequence, but doesn't contain any information about changes before these scenes.

I haven't played through Mass Effect 3 from the start to confirm, however when I replayed the last missions after the Extended Cut was released I started from the beginning of the mission at the Cerberus base as [suggested by Bioware themselves on their website](http://www.masseffect.com/about/extended_cut/#s1q07) but didn't notice any changes in the story up until the beam approach scenes, where rather than controlling the approach yourself the game took control to allow the changes in the Extended Cut DLC to be presented.

[This page](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Storyline_III#Epilogue_2) further details the additions to the epilogue cutscenes based upon your EMS rating at the time of completion.

Comment: Maybe I missed it when I played through originally, but I saw a terminal with some videos on the Illusive Man, with more info on what happens to him at the end. This was just before the boss at Cerberus Base.